# How to load any attributes without using the Mapping ' lazy: false' in Grails

Tags: grails, hibernate-mapping

Constantly faced with a problem when I need to compare and manipulate objects that reference other objects. For example:

```
Class Student {
...
String Name
Integer Age
...
}

Class Stuff {
...
Student student
...
}
```

When I invoke an instance of Stuff (`Stuff.get (id)/load(id)`) and will access the Name, Age and other attribute I see in debug mode (stuff .name = null, they're like 'null' although they are not null. It 
command when analyzing values ​​of these attributes (stuff
.name == "pen") error occurs.

I need to invoke the instances and compare their values ​​to execute business rules, but do not know how to resolve this issue.

I read something about the inclusion in the configuration Stuff Mapping '`student lazy: false`' for all the time you need to load the instance ofstuff , also charge the Student, but that in addition to overload the memory (since stuff is a Domain Great) would solve this case being the only solution to put all references as 'lazy: false' which would slow the application just to make a simple comparison.

Does anyone know how to invoke instances (Stuff), automatically invoking the attribute to be working (student) just to make the comparison of data, without using the '`student lazy: false`' that invokes the data at all times?...

Using Grails 2.2.0 e o Groovy 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Stuff` don't have a property called `name` so you should get `MissingPropertyException` calling `stuff.name`. This has nothing to do with the lazy or eager relationship.

You can check the definition of a lazy relationship [in the documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/lazy.html) and also [the difference between the types of fetch](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#fetching).

To access the name property you need to access the student property before:

```
Stuff instance = Stuff.get(id)
println instance.student.name //this, if lazy, will trigger a new database query.
```

If you know that your code will access the Student instance by the relation with Stuff you could fetch both in one database access (eager and not lazy):

```
Stuff instance = Stuff.withCriteria {
  eq('id', id)
  fetchMode("student", FetchMode.JOIN)
}
```

Comment: Understanding the behavior of Hibernate in Grails is difficult. This command solved the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Grails don't obligate you to know Hibernate, but depending on what you're doing it's good to have this knowledge :-)